# Arabic text encoding in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a file from node.js and inserting Arabic text in it but the output is garbage text instead of Arabic text

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'تمكين و تطوير جمعيات إسكان تعاونية لبناء المساك')
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Siys.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem, I was using webstorm as IDE and create js file from webstorm by default its create file in ancsi encode i just change the encode of my js file and its working fine now anyways Thanks for you quick help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `options` additional parameter?

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'تمكين و تطوير جمعيات إسكان تعاونية لبناء المساك', 'utf8', function(err, data) { 
        /// ... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the same js sample and then running `cat message.txt` I get the Arabic output.
Running `file message.txt` returns `UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators` which is also expected.

My guess is this has to do with notepad not supporting utf8. When I open the file using gedit on Ubuntu it shows the Arabic just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can add encoding in options as below

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'تمكين و تطوير جمعيات إسكان تعاونية لبناء المساك', {encoding: 'utf8'});
```

Also, are you sure that notepad showing arabic text right in the first place ?
try to open it with web browser (chrome, FF) and set encoding to UTF-8 (usually found under developer menu)

[Reference](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)